# Filter not behaving as expected with 0 in an array. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, integer

I have an array of random integers like this: `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 0 ]`, I need to return a new array of either the odd or the even numbers depending on a `wanted` condition.

I tried the following filter method:

```
const result = array.filter(item => {
    const test = item % 2;
    if(wanted === 'odd' && test > 0) return item;
    if(wanted === 'even' && test === 0) return item;
  })
```

and had expected this to work but it only ever returns `[2, 4]` and never `[0, 2, 4]` when the `wanted` is even.

Any thoughts on why this might be the case would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `test` will always be either `1` or `0`. Testing `> 0` is confusing when you're really just looking for `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a boolean from your filter callback, not the item. When you return the item it mostly works, but if the item is zero, that's interpreted as `false`

```js
let arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 0 ]
let wanted = 'even'
const result = arr.filter(item => {
    const test = item % 2;
    if(wanted === 'odd' && test > 0) return true;
    if(wanted === 'even' && test === 0) return true;
  })
console.log(result)
```

You can simplify any just returning the booleans created by your tests:

```js
let arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 0 ]
let wanted = 'even'
const result = arr.filter(item => {
    if (wanted === 'odd') return item % 2
    if (wanted === 'even') return !(item % 2) 
  })
console.log(result)
```

Comment: You can simplify it even more using XOR (binary XOR in fact, which works because the values used are `0`s and `1`s): `arr.filter(item => wanted === "odd" ^ item % 2)`

Comment: I would have never thought of that @ibrahimmahrir. That's pretty cool.

Comment: Thanks guys, that is really helpful and has upgrade my understanding of filter.